# how to run multiple shell scripts in parallel

Tags: bash, shell

I have a few test scripts, each of which runs a test PHP app.  Each script runs forever.

So, `cat.sh`, `dog.sh`, and `foo.sh` each run a PHP script.  Each shell script runs the PHP app in a loop, so it runs forever, sleeping after each run.

I'm trying to figure out how to run the scripts in parallel at the same time.  See the output of the PHP apps in the stdout/term window.

I thought, doing something like the following might work:

```
foo.sh > &2
dog.sh > &2
cat.sh > &2
```

In a shell script it would be sufficient, but it's not working.

```
foo.sh, runs foo.php once, and it runs correctly
dog.sh, runs dog.php in a never ending loop. it runs as expected
cat.sh, runs cat.php in a never ending loop
 *** this never runs!!!
```

It appears that the shell script never gets to run `cat.sh`.  If I run `cat.sh` by itself in a separate window/term, it runs as expected.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get these scripts to run in parallel?

Answer (score 13):

Your current setup is running your commands sequentially.  The first one runs, *and completes*, allowing the second one to start.  The second one never ends, so the third one never gets a chance to start.

Try this:

```
foo.sh >foo.out 2>foo.err &
dog.sh >dog.out 2>dog.err &
cat.sh >cat.out 2>cat.err &
```

That will tell each command to run in the background, and send their output and error information to files.  When a command is run in the background, it detaches from the current session, and allows the next command to run.  It's important to put the ampersand (`&`) as the last character of the line.  Otherwise, it might not get recognized correctly.

Alternately, have each of your shell scripts run the associated `.php` script you're apparently calling with the same semantics as above.  In this scenario, your `foo.sh` might contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
php foo.php >foo.out 2>foo.err &
```

Finally, if you need true parallel operation, check out [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Note: If you really want the output going to the screen/terminal, you can leave off the output redirection:

```
foo.sh &
```

Remember, though, that running multiple commands concurrently can cause confusing output (you may now know what output or errors came from which command), and if you logout, the output has nowhere to go.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for the reply. given that my scenario has each shell test running forever, i really don't want to write the stdout/stderr to a file, rather, i would like to see the output/stderr just displyed to the screen...   i thought running in the background, meant i didn't have to wait for completion before running the next script.. have i missed something..  || also as to the acceptance rate.. i've tried to delete a bunch of things in the past but never could...  in other cases, the answers were totally off base and no help

Comment: Running in the background *does* mean you don't have to wait for completion before running the next script/command.  That's what the `&` at the end of the command does.  If you don't place the ampersand at the end, it doesn't mean the same thing.  Redirecting output to a file (especially for background commands) is usually a good thing, unless they send logs somewhere else (like syslog).  Otherwise, it's easy to get output mixed up between the multiple commands, since they're running at the same time.  I'll update the answer to add a note about output to the terminal.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with parallel command.

Beautiful examples: [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)

```
[me@neo]<bash><~> 19
05:51 Tue Mar 05 > man -f parallel
parallel (1) - run programs in parallel
```

--

```
parallel -j 3 -- "sh foo.sh" "sh dog.sh" "sh cat.sh"
```

This will start 3 scripts in parallel, at the same time.

```
parallel sh -c "echo hi; sleep 2; echo bye" -- 1 2 3
```

This will start by default as many process of the same command, depending of cpu count.

```
parallel -j 3 sh -c "echo hi; sleep 2; echo bye" -- 1 2 3
```

This will force to execute 3 processes at the same time, even if you have just 2 cpu's.

Example:

```
[me@neo]<bash><~> 31 
06:09 Tue Mar 05 > parallel -j 10 sh -c "echo Hello World; sleep 3; echo Good morning" -- $(seq 1 10)

Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
```

Answer (score 2):

Chris has the good general idea for most scripts: end each command with `&` and they'll go into the background. That said, here's my something I keep around for some higher-end tasks. Let me introduce you to my handy toolbox script, `parallel-exec.pl`

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use threads;
    use Thread::Queue;

    my @workers;
    my $num_threads = shift;
    my $dbname = shift;
    my $queue = new Thread::Queue;

    for (0..$num_threads-1) {
            $workers[$_] = new threads(\&worker);
                    print "TEST!\n";
    }

    while ($_ = shift @ARGV) {
            $queue->enqueue($_);
    }

    sub worker() {
            while ($file = $queue->dequeue) {
                    system ('./parser.pl', $dbname, $file);
            }
    }

    for (0..$num_threads-1) { $queue->enqueue(undef); }
    for (0..$num_threads-1) { $workers[$_]->join; }
```

With some light tweaking, you can change the number of threads, provide an array of commands, etc. As this stands right now, it takes the number of threads specified on the command line, a database name, and a list of files to import, then spawns one instance for each file running the specified number at once.

Comment: [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) provides very similar functionality, but that's a handy little bit of Perl.  It never hurts to have multiple options in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

or..you can do it like this:

```
threads=20
tempfifo=$PMS_HOME/$$.fifo

trap "exec 1000>&-;exec 1000<&-;exit 0" 2
mkfifo $tempfifo
exec 1000<>$tempfifo
rm -rf $tempfifo

for ((i=1; i<=$threads; i++))
do
    echo >&1000
done

for ((j=1; j<=1000; j++))
do
    read -u1000
    {
        echo $j
        echo >&1000
    } &
done

wait
echo "done!!!!!!!!!!"
```

every time, it runs 20 threads in parallel.

hope it help :)

Comment: I'd include a `#!` line at the start of the script. The loop writing the initial lines to the fifo should be done in the background to avoid a potential deadlock (just make it `done &`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
./Cat.sh &
./Dog.sh & 
./foo.sh &
```

They will run in background.

For more control on the processes embbed them on a python script using multiprocessing module

```
import multiprocessing as mp 
import os
def Run(script_name):
       os.system('./'+script _name+'.sh)
Pool=[]
For s in [your script list]:
     p=mp.Process(target =Run ,args=(s,))
     Pool.append(p)
For p in P:
     p.start()
Fort p in P:
     p.join()
```